# Hadoop Yarn tasklevel logging with log4j

Tags: hadoop, log4j, mapreduce, task

I have been trying to setup up Hadoop logging at the task level, but with no success so far.

I have modified log4j.properties and set many parameters to DEBUG level:

- log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task=DEBUG
- log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask=DEBUG
- log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask=DEBUG
- log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop = DEBUG

But, I can't see any LOG.info or LOG.debug messages from the tasks being recorded. This is with Yarn being enabled.

I am not sure what I have missed in the configurations to make it work properly. I think I should eventually get these messages in the nodemanage.out log file?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to see your app log messages from the Yarn console but the path to get there has several steps.

1.) go to the Yarn Console, typically http://yourserver:8088
2.) Go to Tools->Local Logs
3.) Find the 'userlogs' link and select it
4.) Find your application, e.g. the MapReduce job name with 'application' prefix instead of 'job' prefix and select it.
5.) Then under the container logs typically 'syslog' you should find your job level logging.

An complete example path is below. 
http://yourserver:8088/logs/userlogs/application_1427820474064_0003/container_1427820474064_0003_01_000019/syslog